# Help installing add-on in GRASS, I get an error message

Tags: grass-gis, viewshed

My Grass gives me this error message, Grass_info_error(4816,1):'make' required. Please install  'make' first. This happens when I attempt to fetch an add-on (r.viewshed). What am I doing wrong? and what is 'make'? Thanks for helping for a Grass newbie. I'm running on Mac Snow Leopard if that makes any difference.

Comment: Install the [Xcode developer tools](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php) and see this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767481/where-can-i-find-make-program-for-mac-os-x-lion) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the Xcode suggestion, but as I have Snow Leopard I can only install Xcode 3.2.2, since 4 is only available through purchase for Snow. I'm still having problems with my attempts to install viewshed. This is the error message at the end of the installation dialog: lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folder
s/58/58wPfZLCFWut1S7Od7Fu7++++TI/-Tmp-//ccj6TYRt.out
make: *** [OBJ.i386-apple-darwin11.4.0/main.o] Error 1
ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may install GRASS 7 in parallel, it contains r.viewshed (so, no need to install it as addon): http://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/mac-osx/